# Excel Add In development,Compatibility of office 2010 and office 2013

Tags: c#, shared, excel-addins, excel-dna

I have used Shared Add In(C#) to develop an Excel Add-In. In the initialization, I had no problem with loading excel-dna file .xll on Office 2010. However, there is problem with running on either Office 2013 or 2016,  showing that "function is Invalid".

```
AddIn udfAddIn = applicationObject.AddIns.Add(progID, true);//the exception is "AddIns is Invalid"
udfAddIn.Installed = load;
```

Please help me. I would like to know how it (.xll file) works on Office 2013 and 2016 by shared add in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different technologies when you make a Shared add-in (a COM add-in) with Excel-DNA. I'm surprised it worked with Excel 2010.

The best approach is to make a new Class Library project (targeting .Net Framework) and then install the ExcelDna.AddIn package from NuGet. Then follow the instructions in the readme file that pops up. You should have a starter add-in that works in both Excel versions.

The best place for Excel-DNA support is the Google group at https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/exceldna

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,I make self-defining function with Excel-DNA.But,I make gui Excel Plugin with Shared add in(C#),I will make a starter add-in that works in more Excel versions